# getting "module not found" error when the library is in the anaconda3/envs/projects_env folder

Tags: python, libraries, modulenotfounderror, anaconda3

i installed python's schedule library in anaconda, the path is like this:
/anaconda3/envs/myprojectenv/schedule

my python3 project is in a separate folder, the path is like this:
/Desktop/projects/myproject.py

when i activate the anaconda3 environment and run my python project, it can't find the schedule library. do the python libraries & packages i install for use in a project need to be in the same directory as that project? because right now i only have it in my anaconda3 environment folder and it can't seem to find it, even with the environment activated.

Comment: How did you install schedule? using pip? and if so which pip

Comment: @kakigadol I used pip 23.2.1 and now i forget if i updated pip after installing schedule. if i had updated pip, would that affect whether my project can access schedule??

Comment: no it won't. but did you use the anaconda's pip? every installation of python has its own pip

Comment: @kakigadol when i was in my environment, i checked pip3 --version and got pip 23.2.1. when i was in base environment, i checked pip3 --version and got the same pip version. does this mean i used the anaconda's pip/is there a better way to tell?

Comment: It doesn't tell anything, you can try run `which python` command and see if it's the same python interpreter (and also `which pip3`)

Comment: i got it working now. thank you for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: So you can answer yourself or close the question